# Relationship between weak and strong closure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E \subset X$ be a convex subset of a normed space. I want to show that the weak closure of $E$ denoted by $\overline{E}_{w}$ is the same as the strong closure of $E$ denoted by $\overline{E}$. By Hahn-Banach, $\overline{E}_{w} \subset \overline{E}$.

Is it true that $\overline{E} \subset \overline{E}_{w}$? My idea is: Let $p$ be a limit point of $E$. Then there exists $p_{n} \rightarrow p$ strongly. Therefore $p_{n} \rightarrow p$ weakly. But does this imply that $p \in \overline{E}_{w}$? If the weak topology was first countable, this would but true, but the weak topology is not, so I can't just say $p$ is a limit point by just looking at sequences. Is there another way to see this?

Comment: A weakly closed set is norm closed; so the norm closure is contained in the weak closure.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Why is a weakly closed set also normed closed? Is this correct? Let $E$ be a weakly closed set. Then complement of $E$ is weakly open. Since the weak topology is weak than the norm topology, every weakly open set is also norm open. Then $E$ is norm closed.

Comment: Yes, that's right.